# How to propagate clicks inside nested custom views?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

If I have an activity which contains a custom view and this custom view again contains another custom view, what would be the best way to propagate the click events in the most nested view to the activity without ending in callback hell and allowing multiple subscribers to these events?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you have `CustomView` that contains inside `AnotherCustomView`.
And you want get `onClickEvent` in Activity from second?

I think, you need to add method `setOnAnotherCustomViewClickListener(listener: OnClickListener)` to your `CustomView`

**Sample:**

```
class CustomView(context: Context) : View(context) {
    val anotherCustomView:AnotherCustomView = AnotherCustomView(context)
    fun setOnAnotherCustomViewClickListener(listener:OnClickListener?){
        anotherCustomView.setOnClickListener(listener)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make getter function for that view inside both custom views. For example:
**MySmallCustomView**

```
public View getCLickableView() {
    return findViewById(R.id.id_clickable_view);
}
```

**MyBigCustomView**

```
public View getNestedCLickableView() {
    MySmallCustomView mySmallCustomView = findViewById(R.id.id_my_small_custom_view);
    return mySmallCustomView.getClickableView();
}
```

And in activity, you can just get reference and set on click listener on it myBigCustomView.getNestedClickableView().setOnClickListener...